# autohotkey, shortcuts, autocorrection

Tags: autohotkey, shortcut, autocorrect

When I'm using Autohotkey script it's not working correctly. What could be the reason???

That's what I'm writing in the script

```
::mn::My name is USER.
return
```

and when I type "mn" it's turning into

```
My namesi SER 
m nme is SE 
my name is USER. 
My naemi s USER.
My naem is USER.
My nam eis USER.
My naime s USER .
my name is USER.
```

but just now I noticed it only happens in Notepad. And in other apps it works correctly for instance in MS edge:

```
My name is USER.
My name is USER.
My name is USER.
```